# error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform. [EPS1] Even I though I am not using arrays I get this error

Tags: fortran

even I am not using arrays but got this error
in the eps1 and eps2 equation, i got this error
    !initial values

```
  real*8 k,etahe,etaox,alphastar,x,epsm,theta,omega
  real*8 eps1
  real*8 eps2

  k=0.21
  etahe = 0.2
  etaox=0
  alpstar=0.01
  x=0.24
  epsm=0.000544617021
  theta=0

  !dispersion relation to obtain wave vector(number) k
  eps1=(1/alphastar*epsm)*[(1-etahe-etaox)/(1-x**2)
 &+4*etahe/(1-4**2*x**2)+16*etaox/(1-16**2*x**2)]

  eps2=(1/alphastar*epsm*x)*[1-(1-etahe-etaox)/(1-x**2)
 &+etahe/(1-4**2*x**2)-etaox/(1-16**2*x**2)]

  eps3=-(1/alphastar*epsm**2*x**2)

  k=omega**2/2*(cos(theta))**2*(eps1*(1+(cos(theta))**2))
 &+sqrt(eps1**2*(1-(cos(theta))**2)+4*(eps2**2)*(cos(tehta)**2))
  stop
  end
```

Comment: You are using an array constructor in your expressions for `eps1` and `eps2`.  Don't use square brackets as if they are parenthesis.  `[1]` is a rank 1 array with a single element.

Comment: Also real*8 and complex*16 are not, and have never been part of standard Fortran and should be avoided - please see stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter. Similarly many of your constants are single precision, while the variables are using higher precision than that - so you are losing accuracy. Also always please use Implicit None. Finally I would strongly recommend breaking your expressions into a number of simpler expressions then combining them - you will find it a lot easier to debug

Comment: Please take the Welcome [tour]. Searching for the error message would help you find the answer.